# What is "Feature Definition Freeze"?

Tags: release-management

In the [Trusty Tahr release schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseSchedule) there are two phases called Feature Definition Freeze and Feature Freeze. It is pretty clear what the latter means but the wiki description of the first is not so clear. What happens with this phase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wiki description is:

> By this date, all features with updates to be landed in main for the
>   release must be named and acknowledged by the Release Team. Having
>   this freeze gives them a chance to identify any features which should
>   be subject to an earlier Partner Update Deadline or Feature Freeze
>   deadline because they are especially risky. The list of features
>   should be sent to the Release Team mailing list.

It's a deadline to get all blueprints set into the appropriate
priority and approved for the next release.

Blueprints should have all Work Items properly defined in the "Work Items"
section.

Also, in order to show up properly on http://status.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-t/,  blueprints
must be marked as approved, have an importance set and targeted to the
release.

[Source](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2012-May/035260.html)

Comment: I agree. Though you quoted the wiki (like the answer above), you did elaborate on your answer (and sourced!)

Comment: This is the definition given by the release manager, what else? See https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2012-May/035260.html

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the [Feature Definition Freeze](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FeatureDefinitionFreeze) wiki page:

> By this date, all features with updates to be landed in main for the release must be named and acknowledged by the [Release Team](http://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-release). Having this freeze gives them a chance to identify any features which should be subject to an earlier [Partner Update Deadline](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PartnerUploadDeadline) or [Feature Freeze](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FeatureFreeze) deadline because they are especially risky. The list of features should be sent to the [Release Team mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-release).

Comment: Simply citing the wiki page when the OP specifically states that he believes the wiki page is vague isn't the most appropriate answer.

Comment: Then the question is off topic, because Ask Ubuntu is not the place to report issues with the text on the wiki page.

Comment: I would advise you take a look at the definition of an [off-topic question](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). This question clearly falls within the boundaries of an on-topic question, especially given the "Anything ... There are no 'dumb' quetions." category. Also, it could very well fall under the "Services provided by Ubuntu" category as acceptable (the Ubuntu Wiki is a service provided by Ubuntu).

Comment: It also falls under the "Bug reports" category.

Comment: Now you're just arguing for the sake of arguing. Nothing about this is would fall under "bug report." The simple fact is, your answer is not an answer and was flagged as such. You provided the OP with information he/she specifically said was not helpful to them for understanding the concept.

Comment: No, I am not. There are hundreds of answers on this site, which are purely excerpts from web pages, in block quotes, that point to that source. If it's not a valid answer, then no other answer is going to be either, as any other answer which _further_ clarifies the wiki page, should be an edit to the wiki page, not an answer here. Thus, it should be a bug report about the wiki page not being clear enough.

Comment: Oh, and also, questions about development releases of Ubuntu are off topic. Such freezes only exist for in-development releases of Ubuntu. Thus, the question is off topic, because it is about a development release.

Comment: @Githlar This *is* an answer. It may not be as good as the other answer, but it is still an answer. Dobey: The question is perfectly on-topic, it is neither a question about a development release nor a bug. It is a question about the release process of Ubuntu.